# How can I create a virtual ethernet interface between two pods in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

The goal is to route all traffic of one pod via another pod. The destination addresses won't necessarily fall into the subnet of the target pod, so a bridge is not a fit for my use case. I'll use the well-known technique for redirecting all traffic, i.e., `0.0.0.0/1` + `128.0.0.0/1`.

Comment: You can't do this easily in Kubernetes, since the cluster itself heavily manages the container network environment.  Kubernetes doesn't even really have separated networks in any useful way, the entire cluster shares a single network.  Service meshes like Istio work by injecting a second container into every pod to act as that network proxy, but that's a very involved setup I'd avoid trying to implement from scratch.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the comment. I think I'll just go with OpenVPN.